# Using different structure alignment settings

Tags: c, visual-studio, structure, memory-alignment

What are the problems of mixing (Visual Studio) C/C++ projects which have different structure alignment options set? I know that I can obviously set the options differently in different projects, but does this have an affect on the behaviour of the output library/application?

Say I have a library, with structure alignment set to 1-byte, would there be a problem if I had an application which links to the library, but has structure alignment set to default? Does it make a difference if the structures of the library are not used by the application?

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure layout is determined by the alignment rules in affect at compilation time. For efficiency reasons, structure members are aligned in way as to make their addresses in memory multiples of 2, 4, 8 or sometimes larger values.

Extra padding in inserted between structure members depending on their sizes and alignment requirements, and extra padding may be added at the end of the structure to allow arrays of structures to keep this alignment valid for members of all array elements.  `malloc` is guarantied to return a pointer aligned for all practical purposes:

*The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement*.

This behavior can sometimes be controlled via compiler switches and or pragmas as seems to be possible with Visual C/C++.

The consequence is important for structures for which said options will produce different padding.  The code to access structure members with be different in the various libraries and programs handling shared data, invoking **undefined behaviour**.

It is therefore strongly advised to not use different alignment options for data structures shared between different pieces of compiled code.  Whether they live in different programs, dynamic libraries, statically linked object files, user or kernel code, device drivers, etc. the result is the same: undefined behavior with potential catastrophic consequences (like any UB).

It only matters for structures used and shared between the incompatible modules, but it is very difficult to keep track over time of who uses and who does not use structure definitions published in shared header files.  Structures that are only used locally and whose definition is not visible should not pose a problem, but only for as long as they stay private.

I you use compile time switches, **all** structures will be affected by these, including standard definitions from the C library, and all structures defined locally or globally in your header files.  Standard include files may have provisions to keep them immune from such discrepancies, but your own structure definitions will not.

Don't do this with compile time switches unless you know exactly why you need to do it.  Don't do this in source code (via pragmas, attributes and other non portable constructs) unless you are a real expert with complete control over every use of your data.

If you are concerned with structure packing, reorder the `struct` members and chose their types appropriately to achieve your goals.  Changing the compiler's packing rules in **highly error prone**.  See http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ for a complete study.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's confirmed what I was thinking with regards to mixing alignment options. The link seems pretty useful too.